# how spread array in interface declaration[golang]?

Tags: go

i have this function declaration and i want return array of interface.
spread(1,2,3) => [4,5,6].
i also searched any place like `play.golang`,`other stackoverflow go tags` but nothing found

```golang
func spread2(a ...interface{}) []interface{} {
        a:=[]int{4,5,6}
        return []interface{}{a}//[[4,5,6]] NO

        return []interface{}{a...} //[4,5,6] YES,i want this; 
                                   //but got error
}
```

the error i got is : 
`syntax error: unexpected ..., expecting comma or }`

Comment: something like javascript spread operator for initialize array or ... [...a,...a]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case `[]interface{}` **input** is same as **output**.
so just return any thing as array is ok

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func spread(a ...interface{}) []interface{} {
    return a
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(spread(1, 2, 3))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Bqgu_A1BCti

Output:

```
[1 2 3]
```

An optimizing compiler may inline the `spread` function.